# Formatting issue in CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to get into web development, specifically CSS right now, and I wanted to do something practical: a simple menu bar. However, I have issues in formatting the anchors of the submenus properly as they take two rows instead of one.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS code:

```
#menu{ 
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    }
#menu li{
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    position: relative;
}
#menu li ul{
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}
#menu li li{
    float: none;
}
#menu li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your issue, [you can accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170863). Then you can also upvote one or several answers with the gray up-arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few options...

changing your CSS to the following give the entire submenu underneath the other main menu items

```
#menu{ 
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    }
#menu li{
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
}
#menu li ul{
    list-style: none;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu li li{
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#menu li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}​
```

This option will slide the top menu items over, which may not be ideal, but hey it's an option...

```
#menu{ 
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    }
#menu li{
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
}
#menu li ul{
    list-style: none;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu li li{
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#menu li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}​
```

Comment: This option will grow with the width of your submenu items if you don't want a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of `li` so that the text can fit.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `width` of `#menu li`.

```css
#menu li{
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
}
```

[Try a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kBJkH/1/).